# how to overload QToolBar.addAction() method

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

How to overload any method in PyQt

```
class Main_Window( QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Main_Window,self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        dialog_window = QAction( '&Create Plugin', self
        dialog_window.triggered.connect(self.showdialog)
        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
#        toolbar.addAction(QIcon("plugin0.png"),'',self.showdialog)
```

I want to overload QToolBar.addAction(self, QIcon icon,callable receiver)

.........

```
        toolbar.addAction(QIcon("plugin0.png"),self.showdialog)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Menubar')
        self.show()

    def showdialog(self):
        d = Dialog_window()
        d.exec_()


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main_Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Subclass `QToolBar` and define your own `addAction(...)` function.

Comment: thanks , but I need some example

Comment: overload to do what ?

Comment: QToolBar.addAction(self, QIcon icon,callable receiver)  this form is not exist

Answer (score 0):

A small quick example...

```
class MyToolBar( QToolBar ) :
    """Class doc
    """

    def __init__( self, parent ) :
        """Class initialiser
        """

        QToolBar.__init__( self, parent )

    def addAction( self, icn, func ) :

        act = QAction( icon, QString(), self )
        self.addAction( act )
```